# On the constant of integration in solving ordinary differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In solved differential equations, does the constant ‘c’ always represent the value of the dependent variable when the independent $ = 0 $ ?

Comment: This is the case in equations such as $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=ay$, where $a$ is a constant.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar ah I see it's in special cases only. Would $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=axy$ also work?

Comment: Solving the above given differential equation gives $$\ln |y|=\dfrac{ax^2}{2}+C\implies y=C_1\exp\left(\dfrac{ax^2}{2}\right)$$ When $x=0$, then $C_1=y(0)$, so, yes, it would work.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thank you, If this was an answer I'd selected it as best :D

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the question; I provided examples of where it'd work, but, as the counterexamples below show, the statement above is false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily: Suppose we have $y = f(x) = e^x + c$

$$f(0) = 1 + c \neq c$$

Comment: In polynomials , we do have that $c = p(0)$

Comment: @hb20007 The above comment by amWhy would be a good exercise.

Comment: @amWhy I am unfamiliar with the notation in your comment. Could you please tell me what 'p' represents and why it's an 'exercise'?

Comment: Oh sure, I'm just using $p(x)$ to denote a **p** olynomial (which we can call $y$, aka, the dependent variable, so $p(0)$ denotes a polynomial $p(x)$ evaluated at $x = 0$. Example: $p(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x + c \implies p(0) = c.$

Answer (score 4):

No. Suppose
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin x$$ then
$$y=-\cos x+c$$

At $x=0$ $$y(0)=-1+c\ne c$$

Comment: Dear Edwin, you do not have to use ``$$<equation>$$`` every time. To do inline equations, simply write ``$<inline equation>$``.